# finding the sum of to n terms of an arithmetic series

Tags: python, list, sum

im a total beginner in python who has just begun to learn all these basic concepts of python. i was making this program to calculate sum to n terms of an arithmetic series but i keep getting an error on line 4. it says the operand is not supported.

this is the program:

```
z=list(input('type the arithemtic progression that you want to add n terms of:'))
a=(z[0])
n=int(input("type the value of n:"))
d=(z[1]-z[0])#this is the common difference d
Sn=(n/2*(2*a+(n-1)*d))
print (Sn)
```

can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: i did try that before too, but its giving me this: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: Did you convert the list to an `int` instead? Lists themselves cannot be converted into integers, only the numbers within. Also, what was the full error?

Comment: oh i didnt know i had to convert the list to an int too. also, what does that 'map' mean in list(map(int, input('type the arithmetic progression that you want to add n terms of:')?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the opposite of that. You can't do `int(my_list)`; you have to apply `int` to the stuff _in_ `my_list`. `map` simply takes a function and applies it to all elements in a list.

Comment: i see, and what does .strip().split())) at the end of this ( list(map(int, input('type the arithmetic progression that you want to add n terms of:').strip().split())) ) mean?

Comment: This is short, so refer to the Python docs if you want a more complete answer. `.strip()` removes whitespace around a string (i.e., at the start and end), so `"  sample text ".split()` would return the string `"sample text"`. `.split()` splits a string by a _separator_; by default, any amount of whitespace. So `"  sample text".strip().split()` would be `"sample text".split()`, which would be the array `["sample", "text"]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you enter in line 4 are strings, you need to convert them to integers like this:

```
int(z[1])-int(z[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't converting the input list into a list of integers, hence subtracting strings while calculating the difference.

```
ap = list(map(int, input('type the arithmetic progression that you want to add n terms of:').strip().split()))
a = ap[0]
n = int(input("type the value of n:"))
d = ap [1]- ap[0] #this is the common difference d
sum_ap = (n/2*(2*a+(n-1)*d))
print (sum_ap)
```

Output:

```
type the arithmetic progression that you want to add n terms of:1 2 3 4 5 6
type the value of n:10
55.0
```